# Transforming to time series object before ARIMA

Tags: r, object, time-series, autoregressive-models

Is it always mandatory to transform the csv file into time series object before performing auto.arima()?

```
x<-read.csv(c://text.csv)
text<-ts(x,frequency=12, start=c(1946,1))
test<-auto.arima(text)
```

Does the transformation is mandatory for arima?

```
Also, is there any minimum number of past lagged terms required for performing effective forecasting through ARIMA?
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sorce code on the line 16 of `auto.arima` you can read `x <- as.ts(x)`, so the function first converts the data to a time series object and so it is not mandatory to supply a time series object.

The number of lags is determined using a performance criteria (mostly AIC) and the procedure starts at lag 0 and goes up until the maximal allowed lag order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response..in the second question i mean to say that does it require some minimum number of terms over which arima could be performed..Can it be possible to perfrom arima on a  single week sales data to forcast the sales for the 1st day of next week.(Monday)